# moving magento's directory

Tags: magento-1.9, install

I originally set up my magento 1.9 site www.atsite.com/demo

and now i am trying to set the site live, at: www.atsite.com
I moved the whole site into the public_html folder and changed the core_config_data to coincide with new site http://atsite.com and the same with the secure site url too.

however now when i go to atsite.com it still is looking for atsite.com/demo and breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you clear the cache to clear out the old settings.  Also check your .htaccess file to make sure you don't have any normalization redirects in there.

Comment: clear the cache... is there a way to do that server side? and what old settings should i look at? i did a search for '/demo' through my database and saw a bunch of things in... log_url_info' table... should i delete that whole table?

Comment: wow im an idiot... forgot about the /var/cache - and the /sessions.... all fixed thanks dude!

Comment: Great, glad it helped.